# Google Maps API with CoffeeScript: infoWindow won't close when user clicks off it

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coffeescript, onclicklistener, infowindow

So it's my first time working with both the Google Maps API and CoffeeScript. We have infoWindows that pop up on marker click, but they only are removed when someone clicks on another marker and brings up a different infoWindow instead, and won't close otherwise. We just need the pop-up box to close when the user clicks away from it. Here's the code we're using (apologies if it's a bit much, I'm not sure where the exact call is supposed to be):

```
        @infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow unless @infoWindow?
        @infoWindow.close()

        places = if @options.places? and @options.places.length > 0 then @options.places else null

        if places?
          # add pins
          @add_pins(places)

          # fit bounds
          if @options.googleMap.setBounds == true
            @set_bounds(places)

        # ie8 hack
        ie_8_map()
        # results
        if @options.resultType == 'floating'
          $(".places-map .overlay").show()

      #######
      add_pins: (places) ->
        @pins = {}
        if @markers
          for marker in @markers
            marker.setMap null

        for place, i in places
          @pins[place.id] = '/assets/pins/'+ String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt()+i)+'.png'
          project_pin = new google.maps.MarkerImage '/assets/pins/'+ String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt()+i)+'.png', new google.maps.Size(40, 63), new google.maps.Point(0,0), new google.maps.Point(20, 63)
          project_pin_shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage '/assets/pin-shadow.png', new google.maps.Size(74, 63), new google.maps.Point(0,0), new google.maps.Point(22, 63)
          marker = new google.maps.Marker map: @googleMap, position: @_latLng(place), icon: project_pin, shadow: project_pin_shadow
          @markers.push marker
          # Adding the pop-up info window
          if place.name
            google.maps.event.addListener marker, 'click', @clickMapMarker.bind(this, place, marker)
        # Add pin pictures
        for k,v of @pins
          pinImg = $(".place-result ." + k + "_place_pin")
          pinImg.parent(".place_pins_popup_img").show()
          pinImg.attr("src", v)

      #######
      clickMapMarker: (place, marker) ->
        @infoWindow.close()
        if @options.resultType == 'leftbar'
          if place.result_html
            @infoWindow.setContent place.result_html
          else
            pop = $('<div class="place-result"></div>').html($('#res_' + place.id).clone().attr("id":"cln_"+place.id))
            pop.find('.place_pins_popup_img').remove()
            #pop.find('.place_pins_popup_img').remove()
            @infoWindow.setContent pop.html()
        else
          @infoWindow.setContent JST["templates/places_map_listings"](places: [place])
        @infoWindow.open(@googleMap, marker)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I'm not familiar with CoffeeScript yet, but from the looks of it you need to add another click event listener on the map so that when the user clicks the map, the InfoWindow closes.

So something like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener @googleMap, "click", ->
  @infoWindow.close()    

# @googleMap.panTo(someGoogleMapLatLng);
# @googleMap.setZoom(someIntZoomLevel);
```